# How can one display different records on different pages?

Tags: php, mysql

For eg I have 5 records of same user. What is the best way I can sort and display each one of them on a different page using next and previous links.For eg on clicking previous i must get previous record. Then i again click previous i must get previous to that record and so on.

Comment: You need Pagination. Search for the same

Answer (score 1):

Pick an order and set it with `ORDER BY [order]`, then use `LIMIT start, amount` to slice the result.